# ANSI SQL Function Dynamic parameter

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I am using below query in Azure Synapse Spar SQL notebook. I need to dynamically give function parameter. Is there a way I could achieve this?

```
select ROUND(
    '9.000083',cast(NumDigitsAfterDecimal as INT)),NumDigitsAfterDecimal from (
SELECT 
        2 NumDigitsAfterDecimal
    ) a
```

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: In which function are you trying to pass dynamic parameter?

Comment: Round Function         select ROUND( '9.000083',cast(NumDigitsAfterDecimal as INT)),NumDigitsAfterDecimal from ( SELECT 2 NumDigitsAfterDecimal ) a

Comment: select ROUND(
    '9.180083',2),NumDigitsAfterDecimal from (
SELECT 
  2 NumDigitsAfterDecimal
 ) a This query is working for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706055/error-when-running-a-query-involving-round-function-in-spark-sql I think i got the answer. Let me try with this.

Comment: `SET NumDigitsAfterDecimal = 2` with your query will `select ROUND( '9.180083',cast(${NumDigitsAfterDecimal} as INT)),NumDigitsAfterDecimal from ( SELECT 2 NumDigitsAfterDecimal) a` will give you [result](https://i.imgur.com/1qc06a1.png)

Comment: Thank you so much Pratik. I actually need it in a single query to use inside a sql merge.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Synapse Spark SQL notebook. I need to dynamically give function parameter.

To set and pass parameter in spark SQL you can try below code:

```sql
SET NumDigitsAfterDecimal =  2;

select ROUND( '9.18456083',cast(${NumDigitsAfterDecimal} as INT)),${NumDigitsAfterDecimal} as NumDigitsAfterDecimal
--OR
select ROUND( '9.180083',cast(${NumDigitsAfterDecimal} as INT)),NumDigitsAfterDecimal from ( SELECT 2 NumDigitsAfterDecimal) a
```

**Execution and output:**
[image]